# Why / when to use `intptr_t` for type-casting in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, types, casting, intptr

I have a question regarding using `intptr_t` vs. `long int`. I've observed that incrementing memory addresses (e.g. via manual pointer arithmetic) differs by data type. For instance incrementing a char pointer adds 1 to the memory address, whereas incrementing an int pointer adds 4, 8 for a double, 16 for a long double, etc...

At first I did something like this:

```
char myChar, *pChar;
float myFloat, *pFloat;

pChar = &myChar;
pFloat = &myFloat;

printf( "pChar:  %d\n", ( int )pChar );
printf( "pFloat: %d\n", ( int )pFloat );

pChar++;
pFloat++;

printf( "and then after incrementing,:\n\n" );
printf( "pChar:  %d\n", (int)pChar );
printf( "pFloat:    %d\n", (int)pFloat );
```

which compiled and executed just fine, but XCode gave me warnings for my typecasting: "Cast from pointer to integer of different size."

After some googling and binging (is the latter a word yet?), I saw some people recommend using `intptr_t`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
...

printf( "pChar:  %ld\n", ( intptr_t )pChar );
printf( "pFloat: %ld\n", ( intptr_t )pFloat );
```

which indeed resolves the errors. So, I thought, from now on, I should use `intptr_t` for typecasting pointers... But then after some fidgeting, I found that I could solve the problem by just replacing `int` with `long int`:

```
printf( "pChar:  %ld\n", ( long int )pChar );
printf( "pFloat: %ld\n", ( long int )pFloat );
```

So my question is, why is `intptr_t` useful, and when should it used? It seems superfluous in this instance. Clearly, the memory addresses for `myChar` and `myFloat` were just too big to fit in an `int`... so typecasting them to `long int`s solved the problem.

Is it that sometimes memory addresses are too big for `long int` as well? Now that I think about it, I guess that's possible if you have > 4GB of RAM, in which case memory addresses could exceed 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 (max value for `unsigned long int`s...) but C was created long before that was imaginable, right? Or were they that prescient?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, binging is a word, which originally meant to indulge in an activity, especially eating, to excess.

Comment: Using `intptr_t` with the printf functions is not portable, there is no format specifier for it. Cast the pointer to a void pointer instead and use the `%p` format specifier.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's the thing: on some platforms, `int` is the right size, but on others, `long` is the right size. How do you know which one is the one you should use? You don't. One might be right, but the standard makes no guarantees about which one it would be (if it is either). So the standard provides a type that is defined to be the correct size, regardless of what platform you're on. Where before you had to write:

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
  typedef long intptr;
#else
  typedef int intptr;
#endif
```

Now you just write:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

And it covers so many more cases. Imagine specializing the snippet above for *every single platform* your code runs on.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the clarification. What if you just used `long` all the time? Wouldn't `long` work with shorter addresses as well? Does the extra memory allocation for `long`s vs `int`s significantly affect performance?

Comment: @caravaggisto - Nope. `long` is only guaranteed to be 32 bits, and may not work on a 64-bit platform. You could always use `long long`, but that doesn't exist before C99. I doubt the allocation matters much. It's more a problem of correctness.

Comment: Right, I see what you're saying with the 64-bit case. I was wondering, if you're only considering 32-bit systems, it seems like `long` would work on all, while `int` would not where '`long` is the right size' as you discuss in your initial answer.

Comment: That is, if you're on a system that has `int` length addresses, `long` would presumably work as well, no? It seems to be an issue of address lengths fitting within the range of a given data type.

Comment: It would work in that sense, but if you use a data type that's too big, perform arithmetic on it, and convert it back to a pointer, you may get incorrect results. `intptr_t` is designed to premit conversion of pointers to _and from_ integers.

Comment: Hmm didn't know that. Glad I stumbled upon `intptr_t`, then. I'm currently going through "Learn C on the Mac" by Dave Mark where so far typecasting has been done with just `int`. Granted I'm only 3/4 thru the book, and there's a section toward the end on typecasting, so perhaps this will be addressed in the text later. Thanks again for the response!

Comment: I would be very skeptical of any C book that teaches you to cast between pointers and integers. Actually almost all casts are indicative of bugs; they're at least a code smell. Pointer/integer casts are much worse.

Comment: @R..: Often an API which provides a callback function, or a messaging API like the Windows message pump, will have an integer data field or two that can be passed around. Your program may need to stuff a pointer into a `DWORD` or an `int` because that is all that is available in the API.

Comment: @ZanLynx WinAPI is a terrible API designed for horribly broken pre-standard C compilers in the mid-80s. It hasn't changed much since the Win16 era. There's a reason why MS is trying to kill it.

Comment: Using `intptr_t` isn't any more portable than using `int` or `long` - it's not guaranteed to exist by C99. You also can't use it with printf. The real problem is you shouldn't be casting a pointer to an integer type. If an API requires you to do that, the API is garbage

Comment: @william_grisaitis even today Microsoft's compiler uses 32 bits for long and 64 bits for a pointer.  They didn't increase the size of long because they wanted to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: @ZanLynx in that situation a better solution is to use an arbitrary integer for the API and have a mapping from those integers to pointers.  As a side benefit it allows you to know when e.g. the callback is to an object that has been deleted.

Answer (score 65):

`intptr_t` is a new invention, created after 64-bit and even 128-bit memory addresses were imagined.

If you **ever** need to cast a pointer into an integer type, **always** use `intptr_t`. Doing anything else will cause unnecessary problems for people who need to port your code in the future.

It took a long time to iron out all of the bugs with this in programs like Mozilla/Firefox when people wanted to compile it on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: It would be better to use `uintptr_t`. Signed types are messy and surely make no sense with pointers...

Comment: Good call. Everything I see written about `uintptr_t` is in the context of c++ and the `inttypes.h` library. looks like it's in `stdint.h`, too, though. any difference?

Comment: Speaking of **always** using `intptr_t` this answer claims that it is not widely available http://stackoverflow.com/a/9492910/1073672 . So what to do then?

Comment: @user10607: It is available from C99 onwards. That's more than a *decade*. So unless you're using an ancient compiler like TurboC or a very exotic platform with no int to hold a pointer, it *will* be available ;)

Comment: @MestreLion that's not true, it's optional in C99

Comment: @Spookbuster true, but my point was it was _introduced_ in C99, almost _two decades_ ago. So availability should not be an issue, even if it was only an optional feature last millenia

Comment: There's a remaining problem, which format string should you pass to `printf` to use `intptr_t`?

Answer (score 14):

First, `intptr_t` is only for data pointers (not functions) and is not guaranteed to exist.

Then, no, you shouldn't use it for the purpose of printing. The `%p` is for that. You just have to cast your pointer to `(void*)` and there you go.

It is also no good for arithmetic / accessing individual bytes. Cast to `(unsigned char*)` instead.

`intptr_t` is really for the rare occasions that you have to interpret pointers as integers (which they really aren't). Don't that if you mustn't.

Comment: thanks. What are pointers, then, if not (binary) integers? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @caravaggisto, this depends a lot on the architecture. Some architectures have segmented memory, so an address is composed of two parts. Just simple integer addition might for example not always give you a valid address. Arithmetic on `unsigned char` will do, provided you allocated a chunk that is large enough.

Comment: `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` could be useful for certain scenarios. For example you are building your own version of `malloc()`, a specialized dynamic memory allocator, perhaps for an embedded system or another computer system where a specialized memory allocator is needed. Say you keep track of deallocated blocks in an explicit free linked list. You could use an intptr_t to store pointers to the next and previous blocks in the linked list. This would not be part of the payload itself, but rather the previous word before it, in a "header" or "footer" of the block.

Answer (score 13):

You could make your life easier by using the `p` conversion specifier:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)foo);
```

Also, the portable way to print a variable of type `(u)intptr_t` is to use the `PRI*PTR` macros from `inttypes.h`; the following is equivalent to using `p` on my platform (32-bit):

```
printf("%08" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)(void *)foo);
```

The casts to `void *` are necessary for full portability, but can be omitted on platforms with uniform pointer representations.

Comment: Although this probably should have been a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf( "pChar:  %ld\n", ( intptr_t )pChar );
printf( "pFloat: %ld\n", ( intptr_t )pFloat );
```

This is wrong. And this is even worse

```
printf( "pChar:  %ld\n", ( long int )pChar );
printf( "pFloat: %ld\n", ( long int )pFloat );
```

> Is it that sometimes memory addresses are too big for long int as well?

Yes, nothing requires `intptr_t` to have the same size as `long`, for example on 64-bit Windows `long` is 32-bit but pointers are 64-bit, or some 128-bit architectures in the future may have 128-bit pointers but shorter `long` type. Therefore this is incorrect

> *Clearly, the memory addresses for `myChar` and `myFloat` were just too big to fit in an `int`... so typecasting them to `long int`s solved the problem*

It only solves the problem on some platforms. You must use [`PRIdPTR` or `PRIiPTR`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) for `intptr_t`. The correct way is like this

```
printf("pChar:  %" PRIiPTR "\n", (intptr_t)pChar);
printf("pFloat: %" PRIdPTR "\n", (intptr_t)pFloat);
```

But why do you need to print the *decimal* values of the pointers? Usually they're supposed to be printed as **hex**. Besides `uintptr_t` is preferred in most cases, especially when doing bitwise arithmetic on pointers (for example for [tagged pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer) or [XOR linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list)) so this is better

```
printf("pChar:  %" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)pChar);
printf("pFloat: %" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)pFloat);
```

> why is `intptr_t` useful, and when should it used

There are very few cases where you need `intptr_t` rather than `uintptr_t`. See [What is the use of `intptr_t`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718120/995714) for some examples