# converting int to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to save `int` value to a pointer variable. But I get an error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int *NumRecPrinted = NULL;
  int no_of_records = 10;
  NumRecPrinted = (int*)no_of_records; // <<< Doesn't give value of NumRecPrinted

  cout << "NumRecPrinted!" << NumRecPrinted;
  return 0;
}
```

I tried doing this but I get 0 as return:

```
int main()
{
    int demo(int *NumRecPrinted);
    int num = 2;
    demo(&num);
    cout << "NumRecPrinted=" << num;    <<<< Prints 0
    return 0;
}

int demo (int *NumRecPrinted)

{
    int no_of_records = 11;
    NumRecPrinted = &no_of_records;
}
```

NumRecPrinted returns as 0

Comment: You never told us what the error was.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There are few good reasons to convert an integer into a pointer, so I am wondering whether what you are trying to do might not be better achieved somehow else. Or do you mean *obtain a pointer to an integer?*

Comment: i am doing this inside a function which needs to return the pointer.

Comment: In your `demo` function, you modify `NumRecPrinted` to point to a local variable... It will not be useful outside `demo`...

Comment: @AJ. I hope you're not planning [a hotel heist](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/46642).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to be doing this:

```
NumRecPrinted = &no_of_records;
```

i.e. you're taking the address of `no_of_records` and assigning it to `NumRecPrinted`.

And then to print it:

```
cout << "NumRecPrinted!" << *NumRecPrinted;
```

i.e. you're dereferencing `NumRecPrinted` which will get the `int` stored at the memory address pointed to by `NumRecPrinted`.

Answer (score 10):

It's sometimes useful to "encode" a non-pointer value into a pointer, for instance when you need to pass data into a *pthreads* thread argument (`void*`).

In C++ you can do this by hackery; C-style casts are an example of this hackery, and in fact [your program works as desired](http://codepad.org/0tFhrF9r):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int *NumRecPrinted = NULL;
  int no_of_records = 10;
  NumRecPrinted = (int*)no_of_records;

  cout << "NumRecPrinted!" << NumRecPrinted; // Output: 0xa (same as 10)
  return 0;
}
```

You just need to realise that `0xa` is a hexadecimal representation of the decimal `10`.

However, this *is* a hack; you're not supposed to be able to convert `int`s to pointers because in *general* it makes no sense. In fact, even in the *pthreads* case it's far more logical to pass a pointer to some structure that encapsulates the data you want to pass over.

So, basically... "don't".

Comment: But if you must ... use [intptr_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326338/why-when-to-use-intptr-t-for-type-casting-in-c)

Comment: ... or at least `static_assert(sizeof(int) >= sizeof(void*), "the size of int must be greater than or equal to the size of a pointer");`, i.e., document your assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int *NumRecPrinted = NULL; // assign pointer NumRecPrinted to be valued as NULL
int *NumRecPrinted2 = NULL;
int no_of_records = 10; // initialize the value of the identificator no_of_records 
NumRecPrinted = (int*)no_of_records; // sets a pointer to the address no_of_records
NumRecPrinted2 = &no_of_records; // gives a pointer to the value of no_of_records

cout << "NumRecPrinted!" << NumRecPrinted;  // address of no_of_records 0000000A
cout << "NumRecPrinted!" << *NumRecPrinted2; // value of no_of_records 10
system("pause"); // ninja 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why no indentation? And why did you add `system("pause")`? Doing that makes baby jesus cry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int *NumRecPrinted = NULL;
  int no_of_records = 10;
  NumRecPrinted = &no_of_records; // take the address of no_of_records

  cout << "NumRecPrinted!" << *NumRecPrinted; // dereference the pointer
  return 0;
}
```

Note the added ampersand and the asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

`(int *)no_of_records` gives you a pointer to the address `no_of_records`. To get a pointer to the value of `no_of_records`, you need to write `&no_of_records`.

Answer (score 0):

I really like using union for this sort of stuff:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*));

  union { int i; int* p; } u { 10 };

  cout << "NumRecPrinted! " << u.p;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is undefined behavior in C++.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to understand relationship between pointers and integers. They all can be represented as numbers and converted back and forth. Let's look at following example:

```
int main()
{
    // pointer to int64_t
    int64_t* pointer = new int64_t(5);
    // an integer keeping address of the pointer in decimal format
    int64_t pointerAsNumber = (int64_t) pointer;
    // pointer to int64_t created from  int64_t integer
    int64_t* pointerFromNumber = (int64_t*)pointerAsNumber;

    // both print 5 - number stored in memory cell with address "pointer"
    cout << *pointer << endl;
    cout << *pointerFromNumber << endl;

    // both print same number - the address of memory cell that stores number 5
    // the printed numbers may differ between different program runs
    cout << pointer << endl;
    cout << pointerFromNumber << endl;

    // print address of the memory cell that holds 5 in decimal format
    cout << pointerAsNumber << endl;
    // print address of the memory cell that holds 5 in hexadecimal format
    // note, all 4 printed numbers, pointer, pointerFromNumber, pointerAsNumber and 
    //(hex) << pointerAsNumber are same numbers
    cout << (hex) << pointerAsNumber << endl;

    // now three DIFFERENT numbers will be printed
    // they hold addresses of pointer, pointerFromNumber and pointerAsNumber
    cout << &pointer << endl;
    cout << &pointerFromNumber << endl;
    cout << &pointerAsNumber << endl;

}
```

I find specially useful possibility to convert user defined data types to and from integers.
Here is another example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    MyStruct(int a_, int b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {}
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct* ms = new MyStruct(1,2);
    // storing address of ms in msaddr ;
    uint64_t msaddr = (uint64_t)ms;
    // creating another MyStruct from the address
    MyStruct* ms2 = (MyStruct*)(msaddr);
   // the both MyStruct keep same numbers
    cout << ms->a << endl;
    cout << ms->b << endl;
    cout << ms2->a << endl;
    cout << ms2->b << endl;

   // but they are different structs in memory
    cout << &ms << endl;
    cout << &ms2 << endl;
}
```

Keep in mind, the demonstrated possibilities of converting between integers and pointers are not recommended and should be used with great caution, when at all.