# Why can't I assign an integer value to an integer pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, clang++

My code is

```
int null = 0;
int *p = null;
```

It gives me an error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an lvalue of type 'int'.

In C it would work.

**EDIT:**

How can I make it work in this spirit?

It's from an exercise (2.32) from the Primer C++ book:

*Is the following code legal or not? If not, how might you
make it legal?*

```
int null = 0, *p = null;
```

Comment: I think you're just missing a cast.

Comment: Why should it? They're not the same type. If you really do want to do that you'll need a cast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting int to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212219/converting-int-to-pointer).

Comment: Not a duplicate - 0 is special (linked question used 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C++11 then use `nullptr`:

```
int *p = nullptr;
```

If you are not using C++11 then use `NULL` instead:

```
int *p = NULL;
```

Do not define your own `null` value at all, since C/C++ already has one of its own.  `NULL` has no type, it is simply defined as `0`, and an integer literal `0` can be assigned to a pointer:

```
int *p = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

change `int *p = null;` to `int *p = (int*)null;`

Comment: I've done this from the first time but a get a warning: cast to 'int *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Comment: That warning suggests you are compiling for 64-bit, where a pointer is 8 bytes in size but an `int` is 4 bytes in size.

Comment: I was wondering if there would be something else that could do the job, just for the experience of playing with C++, especially from the time that the book hasn't even mention typecasting yet. I'm with you guys but is there something that I miss?

Comment: @gon1332: What job, exactly, are you trying to do? Convert an int to a pointer? The book is not asking you to do that. It's just asking you how to fix the code. And the correct way to fix the code is to change the second `null` to `nullptr`, or perhaps `&null` (so p points to the int `null`). If you want to convert an int to a pointer though, you need a cast.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The answer is to initialize with nullptr or with the literal 0.

Comment: Use `(long*)null` instead of `(int*)null`. It should eliminate warning.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nullptr` in C++11. C++ doesn't do automatic conversion between int and x* (where x is type), so using an `int` typed variable to define null won't work. In pre-C++11, you can use integral literals, like `0`. (You can still use integral constants after the new standard, but there are good reasons for using `nullptr` over `NULL`.  [What are the advantages of using nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816385/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-nullptr))

You can read more about it `nullptr` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr.

Comment: how could I make the above work as it is, without nullptr? I'm new in C++.

Comment: If you are using C++11 then use `nullptr`: `int *p = nullptr;`.  If you are not using C++11 then use `NULL` instead: `int *p = NULL;`.  Do not define your own `null` value at all, C/C++ already has one.  `NULL` has no type, it is simply defined as `0`, and an integer literal `0` can be assigned to a pointer: `int *p = 0;`

Comment: I'm now learning C++ and I read the Primer C++. It is one excersise (2.32). The solution that you suggested is the one that came first. I was wondering if there would be something else that could do the job, just for the experience of playing with C++.

Comment: @gon1332: Any "null pointer constant" would work, which includes `false` and `0L`. But that's obscure and obsolete; use `nullptr`. It's safer.

Comment: @gon1332 You don't have to select answers if they don't answer the question you asked. This one doesn't (it doesn't explain why `int* p = 0;` works, and seems to claim `NULL` wouldn't work, which is wrong). By selecting it, you make it less likely that someone else will come and actually answer your question.

Comment: The correct answer is that with `nullptr` or `NULL`. @RemyLebeau answered it correctly. If he posts I'll accept him. You're right about `NULL`. Both `nullptr` and `NULL` will work.

Answer (score -2):

I think *p is not a correct identifier for C. this is because a good identifier shouldn't start with a symbol but a letter.

Comment: *p means p is a pointer its not included in name identifier :))

Comment: thank you for this comment and let me know something i don't know before.