# Swap two pointers using XOR

Tags: c, swap, xor

I have a quick question about using XOR two swap two string literals.

so I have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void intSwap(int *a, int *b){
    *a=*a^*b;
    *b=*a^*b;
    *a=*a^*b;
}


void swapString(char **a, char **b){
    char *temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

void main(){
    char *s= "ha";
    char *t= "Oh";

    printf("%s and %s \n",s,t); // prints ha Oh
    swapString(&s,&t);
    printf("%s and %s \n",s,t); // prints Oh ha


    int a=10;
    int b=5;
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b); //print 10 5
    intSwap(&a,&b);
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b); //print 5 10
}
```

As you can see, I used binary operation XOR to for the intSwap. However, when I tried to do the same thing with swapString, it's not working.

I get error message saying: invalid operands to binary ^ (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)

Do you know how to use XOR to swap two string literals? Is it possible in C? Thanks ahead!!

Comment: I hope you are not going to use this code in any production application. If you do, you have to add extra logic to make sure that calling `intSwap(&a, &a)` doesn't mess things up.

Comment: Why not just simply use a temporary. It's usually faster.

Comment: @RSahu: Or just make the pointers `restrict` and leave it up to the caller, same way `memcpy` does.

Answer (score 9):

There are no bitwise operations on pointers. The only "arithmetic" operations that can act on them are `+` and `-` (and their childer `++`, `--`, `+=` and `-=`). So you need to cast to `intptr_t` (or preferably `uintptr_t` when doing bitwise operations) and back.

```
void pointerXorSwap(int **x, int **y){
    uintptr_t a = (uintptr_t)*x;
    uintptr_t b = (uintptr_t)*y;

    a = a ^ b;
    b = a ^ b;
    a = a ^ b;

    *x = (int*)a;
    *y = (int*)b;
}
```

Anyway, it's a bad practice and won't save you any cycles. The compilers will recognize swaps using simple assignments and optimize it for you. Good compilers even recognize those XOR pessimizations and **convert them back to the more efficient MOVs**. [Here are some examples](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwskEF8LAhuwcADAEFTZgG6o86VQAdbBzMQAaJAMoB3Jg4gKBKoAVMEAHqSqgSHBAJ4AlBwA7HzmqumqIoEOBMQA%2BkFM6rIAIqoQWQY5%2BQTx4RqpZhmZ2bkFqgBGxWUVrTV1sQ2WzcMZRRpl4wCs2J1DaRldE6rTsx3zTWPdK%2Bozc7KNo%2Bnh2wEGwfFMG81xp4EX6weWySXP5jZ2UQY%2BfmdBwXk8sRMLpiHhkIVItEAUCQblwUEOvF1CkjiFVstgo9GjcljNMVcngtjhjSiFsc8kq9zFJ4oxpFMpKQWNITEzUNJNPx%2BKphGIJOouLJaEyCKzaXSANYgWSyAB0ssVSuVADZ6VIACxMllSNmkDlSJmCEAmUhi3W00hwWBINAAWwceAYrnIlHtjudxBAwAAHLJSAAzJ0EVzGiAdcWkDoKJjEWLSEWke12zAGADyLAY8YtpCwdtYwGdkfwwIheCsIMjmDCmGQIhDCaZgUwDEjDDwHWIsdimgwkikifhdsbdOYbBQ3N4jA7xsgdNQOTwqBYxqkAFo07IjaJxJJaKOGdrIwawj6VWuVRrVMBkMhVD6FeVcIQSILhZFew6na43/vVFzeH4UVxXiKUZXlZVIMVNVW01Jlh1oExTR1PUDSNE0zRAq0YEQFBUC/T1XQgd1vy9JQCx9JDA2DUNKAjHNoxYbtGyTfCU3TTNsz1PMCyLHMS1rAhy0rHNq1ret%2B0TZtYL1dtO27XssBYocR0YAsJ0Aqc5NnCB50XZdVw3LchB3CQ6APKRGWZY9pFPc9L1Uci2HvOUTFcp98CIYhfw/fCPR/OQuGRAC%2BF4YCLVA0hpVlBUoMg9UtWsnM0KEDDzTZSLYK4I9kukcKMrpCtiEEJcWQ1IA%3D%3D). As you can see, the above function will be compiled to the following instructions

```
pointerXorSwap(int**, int**):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsi], rax
        ret
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using C99 or greater, you need to cast the `char *` to `intptr_t` before operating, then cast back into a `char *` after operating.

Your error message:

> invalid operands to binary ^ (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)

Tells you that you while you got the concept right, the operator `^` doesn't work on pointers.

Note that if your goal is to do this without using an extra variable (note this is **not** actually more efficient on modern compilers), you can do this using addition and subtraction, which pointers do support well enough. [See this site](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR) for details.

`intptr_t` is an integer type that's intended to hold pointer values. Note `intptr_t` is not strictly speaking fully portable (there may not be an integer type that can hold pointers) [per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9492910/1339987).

Answer (score 1):

`*a=*b;` means one char of `b` will be copied to `a`, not the whole string. The same applies to `swapString` function so this will produce the wrong value.

If you try the same with a string with length 1 this will work