# C: How to safely and properly pass several arguments to a pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Consider this simple code:

```
void* threadFunction(void* arg) {

    int argument=(int)arg;

    printf("%d recieved\n", argument);

    return NULL;
}


int main(int argv, char* argc[]) {

    int error;
    int i=0;
    pthread_t thread;

    int argument_to_thread=0;

    if ((error=pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadFunction, (void*)argument_to_thread))!=0) {
        printf("Can't create thread: [%s]\n", strerror(error));
        return 1;
    }

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);


    return 0;
}
```

This works, but two things bother me here.
First, I want to send more than one argument to threadFunction().
Of course, I can pass a pointer to an array, but what if I want to pass two arguments of different types? (say an `int` and `char*`) How can it be done?

The second thing that bothers me here, is the warnings I get when compiling the above...

```
test2.c: In function ‘threadFunction’:
test2.c:8:15: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  int argument=(int)arg;
               ^
test2.c: In function ‘main’:
test2.c:24:59: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  if ((error=pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadFunction, (void*)argument_to_thread))!=0) {
                                                           ^
```

Now, I can make this go away by doing this:

```
if ((error=pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadFunction, (void*)&argument_to_thread))!=0) {
    printf("Can't create thread: [%s]\n", strerror(error));
    return 1;
}
```

But let's say I don't want to pass it by reference... Is there way to pass, say... an int, by value as an argument without the compiler warning me?

Comment: Stil you can pass pointer to struture...

Comment: Yeah, a lot of the time you need to create a `struct` specifically for thread-start arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use `malloc` to obtain storage for the arguments structure, and have the new thread be responsible for calling `free` once it's done with the arguments. (Note: if `pthread_create` fails, you need to `free` this storage in the failure path.)
2. Use a semaphore (or other synchronization, but a semaphore is by far the lightest).

Here's an example of the latter:

```
struct args {
    int a;
    char *b;
    sem_t sem;
};

void *thread_func(void *p)
{
    struct args *args = p;
    int a = args->a;
    char *b = args->b;
    sem_post(args->sem);
    ...
}

    /* in caller */
    struct args args;
    args.a = ...;
    args.b = ...;
    sem_init(&args.sem, 0, 0);
    pthread_create(&tid, 0, thread_func, &args);
    sem_wait(&args.sem);
    ...
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, this is the right answer.

Comment: Why do I need to protect the arg struct? or more precisely, **what** do I need to protect the arg struct from? who else is going to try and access the arg struct? the newly created thread will be the only one accessing it, won't it?

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated, given OP's example.

Comment: @so.very.tired: Unless the same function that called `pthread_create` also calls `pthread_join` before it returns (in which case, creating a thread to do the work was probably rather pointless), the new thread's access to the pointed-to argument is not synchronized with the end of the pointed-to argument's lifetime. In particular the function can return first, in which case the new thread will access junk.

Comment: @R.. So it actually protects me from accessing junk, rather than the danger of two threads accessing the same memory segment...?

Comment: @so.very.tired: Without the synchronization, the code simply invokes undefined behavior by accessing an object after the end of its lifetime. In practice, what will happen is that you read a value from the parent thread's stack where the argument used to be located. This *might* still happen to contain the right value, or it might contain something new put there by whatever function the parent is now executing. But you cannot rely on it, and formally, since it's UB, anything could happen.

Comment: I see... Although, I'd probably won't need it in my case, since the pthread-creating function will not return until the thread is finished. 
You might say it is a bad practice, but for my (small) purposes, it is fine. I did learn something new about safety though... :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass by value but make the warning go away, use this cast:

```
(void *)(uintptr_t)argument_to_thread
```

The intermediate cast through `uintptr_t` avoids the size mismatch. Similarly, when casting back, use:

```
(int)(uintptr_t)voidptr_arg
```

As noted in the comments, the above approach is not necessarily recommended because it relies on implementation-defined behavior. A fully portable approach, assuming you don't need the full range of `int` but only a small range, is:

```
static const char int_to_ptr_trick[MAXVAL];
void *ptr = int_to_ptr_trick + int_val;
int int_val = (char *)ptr - int_to_ptr_trick;
```

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492798/using-intptr-t-instead-of-void

Comment: No it does not. The behavior of such conversions is implementation-defined, not undefined.

Comment: There is no guarantee that intptr_t is wider that int. I wouldn't use this code anywhere.

Comment: I don't necessarily recommend this approach unless you know that (1) the range of values you need to represent fits in `uintptr_t`, and (2) you know that the implementation-defined conversion from `uintptr_t` to `void *` is such that it has the property of preserving all values in the range you care about under round trips. These properties are true on every single POSIX or POSIX-like system I'm aware of, but I agree it's preferable not to rely on them. There's a similar approach however that is 100% portable.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the address of the integer.

```
int argument = 123 ;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadFunction, &argument)) ;
```

and in the thread function

```
 int argument= *(int*)arg ;
```

If you wish to pass more than one argument you can create a struct holding your values, using the same approach as with the above example.

You cannot pass an integer by value if the parameter for the functions is void*. You will have to provide the address of the variable or struct.

Comment: This is definitely wrong; in the absence of any synchronization, `argument`'s lifetime may end before `threadFunction` can access it.

Comment: @R.. It is not, if you look at OP's problem. I was using a local variable intentionally. My answer is correct given the sample code.

Comment: pthread_join(thread, NULL);

Comment: Your code does not work; it has unsynchronized access.

Comment: @R.. There is no such problem, using this in the sample code from OP.