# Properly casting a `void*` to an integer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I'm dealing with some code that uses an external library in which you can pass values to callbacks via a `void*` value.

Unfortunately, the previous person working on this code decided to just pass integers to these callbacks by casting an integer to a void pointer (`(void*)val`).

I'm now working on cleaning up this mess, and I'm trying to determine the "proper" way to cast an integer to/from a `void*`. Unfortunately, fixing the *use* of the void pointers is somewhat beyond the scope of the rework I'm able to do here.

Right now, I'm doing two casts to convert from/to a void pointer:

```
static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(void_p))
```

and

```
reinterpret_cast<void *>(static_cast<intptr_t>(dat_val))
```

Since I'm on a 64 bit machine, casting directly (`(int)void_p`) results in the error:

```
error: cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
```

The original implementation *did* work with `-fpermissive`, but I'm trying to get away from that for maintainability and bug-related issues, so I'm trying to do this "properly", e.g. c++ casts.

Casting directly to an int (`static_cast<int>(void_p)`) fails (`error: invalid static_cast from type 'void*' to type 'int'`). My understanding of `reinterpret_cast` is that it basically just causes the compiler to treat the address of the value in question as the cast-to data-type without actually emitting any machine code, so casting an `int` directly to a `void*` would be a bad idea because the `void*` is larger then the `int` (4/8 bytes respectively).

I *think* using `intptr_t` is the correct intermediate here, since it's guaranteed to be large enough to contain the integral value of the `void*`, and once I have an integer value I can then truncate it without causing the compiler to complain.

Is this the correct, or even a sane approach given I'm stuck having to push data through a void pointer?

Comment: Use a `unsigned long long int` or `uint64_t`, to make it fitting for 64 bit length pointers.

Comment: So, you are round-tripping an `int` through a `void*`, never vice versa, right?

Comment: And did using `intptr_t` actually solve the problem regarding the cast error? It's in fact the right type to use.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Yep. Starts as an `int`, ends as an `int`. It has to pass through a library that only accepts `void*`, though it doesn't alter them (it's a C library with a C++ wrapper, which is why it likes `void*`).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Yeah, it works with `intptr_t`, it's just I'm not totally sure I'm approaching the issue from the correct angle. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492798/using-intptr-t-instead-of-void) doesn't seem to imply that `intptr_t` is a great approach here (what is it for, otherwise?), but most of the other solutions I've found involve a lot of rework which I'm really uncomfortable doing considering the size of the existing codebase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think using `intptr_t` is the correct intermediate here, since it's guaranteed to be large enough to contain the integral value of the `void*`, and once I have an integer value I can then truncate it without causing the compiler to complain.

Yes, for the reason you mentioned that's the proper intermediate type. By now, if your implementation doesn't offer it, you probably have more problems than just a missing typedef.

> Is this the correct, or even a sane approach given I'm stuck having to push data through a void pointer?

Yes, given the constraints, it's quite sane.
You might consider checking the value fits instead of simply truncating it upon unpacking it from the `void*` in debug-mode, or even making all further processing of that integer use `intptr` instead of `int` to avoid truncation.

You could also consider pushing a pointer to an actual `int` instead of the `int` itself though that parameter. Be aware that's less efficient though, and opens you to lifetime issues.

Comment: The values are basically integer constants in the code which are used to select the a further function-call  in the callback. They're compile-time defined, and don't even exceed 10 in any case.
As to why the (apparently slightly nuts) original author didn't just register a different callback for each option (the functions are even defined!) I don't know.

Answer (score 8):

Based on your question, I am assuming that you call a function in some library, passing it a `void*`, and at some point later in time, it calls one of your functions, passing it that same `void*`.

There are basically two possible ways to do this; the first is through explicit casting, as you showed in your current code.

The other, which Deduplicator alluded to, is a little less efficient, but allows you to maintain control of the data, and possibly modify it between when you call the library function, and when it calls your callback function. This could be achieved with code similar to this:

```
void callbackFunction(void* dataPtr){
    int data = *(int*)dataPtr;
    /* DO SOMETHING WITH data */
    delete dataPtr;
}
void callLibraryFunction(int dataToPass){
    int* ptrToPass = new int(dataToPass);
    libraryFunction(ptrToPass,callbackFunction);
}
```

Which one you should use depends on what you need to do with the data, and whether the ability to modify the data could be useful in the future.

Comment: No need to add dynamic allocation (and a memory-leak): Just use `&dataToPass` directly.

Comment: @Deduplicator it depends on the model. My answer as-is works even if the callback is kept to be called later, but does not work if it is called twice (and as you point out, leaks if it is never called), while your suggestion works if it is called multiple times or not at all, but will likely cause a stack corruption if it is kept and called after `libraryFunction` returns. Which is correct depends on the exact scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Is this the correct, or even a sane approach given I'm stuck having to push data through a void pointer?"*

Well, regarding *correct* and *sane* its seriously debatable, especially if you are the author of the code taking the `void*` in the interface.

> I think using `intptr_t` is the correct intermediate here, since it's guaranteed to be large enough to contain the integral value of the void*, and once I have an integer value I can then truncate it without causing the compiler to complain.

Yes, that's the right type to use with a `reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>`, but you'll need to be sure, that a `intptr_t` pointer type has been passed in, and the address is valid and doesn't go out of scope.

---

It's not so unusual to stumble over this problem, when interacting with [c](/questions/tagged/c) API's, and these are offering *callbacks*, that allow you to pass in *user-data*, that will be handled transparently by them, and never are touched, besides of your entry points<sup>1</sup>.

So it's left up to the client code being sure about how that `void*` should be ***re-interpreted*** safely.

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>A classical example for this kind of situation, is the [`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) function</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You have little choice but to use static and reinterpret cast here. Casting to an int will result in loss of precision, which is never ideal. Explicitly casting is always best avoided, because sooner or later what is being casted can change and there will be no compiler warnings then. But in this case you understandably have no choice. Or do you?

You can change the callback definitions on your side to be intptr_t or long int rather than void*, and it should then work and you will not have to do any type casts...