# reinterpret_cast<int*> fails when referencing a void function

Tags: c++, memory

I'm posting this question here because I'm having an issue at the memory level not the coding level currently I ran the below code

```cpp
void* Newnumber;
int* ptr;
Newnumber = &dbCircle;
ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(Newnumber);
        
*ptr = 1; //memory error here why?

dbCircle(x, y, RADIUS); //Void function(int, int, int);
```

This code run in let's say int main()  will compile fine but will produce this error:

> Unhandled exception at program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
> writing location 0x004e9e20

Why?  essentially this should work as I'm trying to say if you return 1 point to function dbCircle and go from there

What I expect is if 1 is returned to point to void dbCircle function using a reference but for some reason I reach a complex memory error even though the code builds fine. To reproduce you can use any void function that returns 3 ints

Comment: `ptr` holds the address of the function `dbCircle` (i.e. it's code). You cannot write to this memory and hence `*ptr = 1` is illegal.

Comment: "I'm trying to say if you return 1 point to function dbCircle and go from there" - But that's not even close to what your code is actually saying. What even makes you think it is?

Comment: What are you trying to do? An access violation or some other crash is pretty much expected for trying to write to a function

Comment: I don't think you understand the task of course I could actually write an if statement that if 1 is true go to function I don't want that.  I want to make dbCircle have an object ID of 1 which is why I'm using casting 1 to point to dbCircle.

Comment: Maybe a [mre] would help explain what you're trying to do, it makes no sense to me

Comment: You have misunderstood some fundamental things, but it's not obvious what. "I want to make dbCircle have an object ID of 1 which is why I'm using casting 1 to point to dbCircle" makes no sense at all.

Comment: For a different Function let's say I have void function (int); If I return this as void function(1); I want 1 to point to the dbCircle function. So the logic is void function(1) = dbCircle function.

Comment: If you need objects then you don't need functions, but classes or structs. E.g if you want a circle with an id, a position and a radius . `struct Circle { int id;  double x; double y; double radius };`.  Also note that in C++ pointers are usually not the solution you will need first.

Comment: And functions can return values too. So you can have a function `int f(int n)` that does calculations on n and returns the result. I think you will be best helped with some more C++ training : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-functions/, https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/classes-and-class-members/

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you describe what you actually want to accomplish? (Not the code you want to write but your ultimate goal.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes that thought occured to me too.  I think he tried to explain, but it is not fully clear to me either. What I understood : "I want a circle with an id of one" which seems like he needs a struct/class.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to have a program navigate to functions by the use of numbers so in this case if a function returns 1 here go to another function to control.

Comment: So, `if (some_value == 1) { dbCircle(x, y, RADIUS); }`? Or using a table of functions, like `my_functions[some_value](x, y, RADIUS);`?

Comment: Example: FunctionA(1);
1 points to FunctionB(3,4,5)   // Pointer to this function is 1 which is why I casted in the 1st place its not supposed to modify it only navigate to the function in code.

Comment: A number can't "point" to a function. If you want to associate a number with a function, or with a specific function call, you need to use one of the methods  I suggested. (And I would recommend reading a bit more in a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) as you seem to have some serious misconceptions.)

Comment: Misconceptions No you have the option to change pointers in C++ I'm trying to turn 1 into a pointer for my function which is possible as I got it to compile even get past the code below example works as now I'm able to past the logic
dbCircle(x, y, RADIUS);
int i = 1;
  
     void** Newnumber;
  int* ptr;
  *Newnumber = *dbCircle;
  
        Newnumber = reinterpret_cast<void**>(ptr);
        ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(Newnumber);
  
        *ptr = i;
CDllHelper Newmodule;
  Newmodule.objAIStart();
  Newmodule.objAIAddEnemy3(2,1,3);

Comment: That code technically works but when I attempt to access number 1 at objAIAddEnemy it still fails that I'm not sure why.

Comment: @DB_Coding I rolled back you edit, because you should not modify the question in a significant way after you have a valid answer. Please post a new question if you like.

Comment: BTW I don't understand why the question was closed due to missing details or clarity. I think it is very clear. Voted to re-open.

Comment: It looks like you're using some sort of game engine which uses integers to identify game objects, and you're trying to tie one such ID (`1`) to one of your own (C++) objects that'd be a circle with `x`, `y` and `radius`. Is that right? In that case, you will need to see how the engine allows you to create custom objects and instantiate them, there's no way to do it from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

> "I'm trying to say if you return 1 point to function dbCircle and go
> from there"

Your intention is not entirely clear.
But your code definitely does **not** do anything like that.

This line:

```
Newnumber = &dbCircle;
```

Is assigning `Newnumber` to the address of the function `dbCircle`, i.e. the address where the code for the function resides.

This line:

```
ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(Newnumber);
```

Is assigning `ptr` to that same address, interpreted as if it was containing a valid `int` (which is doesn't).

Now this line:

```
*ptr = 1; //memory error here why?
```

It attempting to write `1` in the address stored in `ptr`, i.e. **the address of the code** for `dbCircle`.
Since this is illegal you get an access violation runtime error.

Comment: reinterpret_cast isn't rewriting the address its rewriting the pointer that navigates to the address  I'm not trying to change the address of the code here

Comment: @DB_Coding, when you use `*ptr = 1`, you attempt to write to the location in memory the pointer is pointing to. The problem is that it points to the function's code. I.e. the problem is not the `reinterpret_cast` itself, but the fact that you assign the pointer the address of a function.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, this is the reason for the access violation you got, in the original posted code.

Comment: Just because you posted the answer doesn't make it right there is a way to do this I just never done it before.  My question is not invalid a similar question or task was performed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768714/properly-casting-a-void-to-an-integer-in-c so again the answer you provided is wrong

Comment: No. The post you mentioned above is different. In that case the address assigned to the pointer was not the address of the code of a function like in your code. It was an integer value and it was cast to a void*.  Some other comments above tried to explain the issue of assigning a function address to a data pointer as well. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74885577/reinterpret-castint-fails-when-referencing-a-void-function./74885698#comment132158754_74885577.