# Casting malloc to a primitive type

Tags: c, pointers, casting, malloc

How is this allowed in C?

```
int p= (int) malloc (sizeof(int));
```

I only get a warning when I compile in gcc.

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

A void pointer cannot be casted to a primitive type right?

```
*((int*)(x))//is allowed - assume x is of type void*
```

But how is direct cast to primitive also allowed?

Comment: Actually you can cast.

Comment: yes. It's allowed so that you can cast a pointer to [`intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6326338/995714).

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: The ability to cast pointers to integer types predates the existence of `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`.

Comment: C allows a lot of things that might be poor practice. The language depends on programmers to know what they're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not forbidden, but implementation defined behaviour. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

That is why compiler emits the *warning*.

That said, quoting chapter 7.20.1.4, *Integer types capable of holding object pointers*, we have `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`.

> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> `intptr_t`
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> `uintptr_t`

---

Having said that, just for sake of completeness's sake, let me add that, [there is fair amount of reasons on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).